# Pull in through batch the folder name, as part of the full path name, where a file is located?

Tags: batch-file, directory

I know that %~n1 allow a file name to get into a path. How to get in batch the folder name where a file is located?

example: Doing this call

```
          myFolder.bat "Temp\file1WithSpaces.txt"
```

I pull the name of file "file1WithSpaces" by

```
           %~n1
```

I just want to pull "Temp". 
You are also guessing that "Temp\file1WithSpaces.txt" is a relative path

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `%~p1`  ?

Comment: yes, I tried it but it outputs full path except the drive letter

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for /f ^delims^=^" %%A in ("%~dp1\..") do  echo %%~nA
```

Comment: it jumps "Temp" for getting out its direct parent. For example according to what you have written, if "Nouveau dossier" is direct parent of "Temp", we get as output "Nouveau".

Comment: So the problem is with files contain spaces?If yes check the edit in the answer.

Comment: spaces is not only the problem. Instead of taking "Temp", that retrieves its parent

Comment: if you are sure that your parameter will contain a file path only in two parts you can use `for` to split it: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%A in ("%~1") do  echo %%~nA`